# Game breaking bug in Metal Gear Solid V , already spoiled 4 things for me

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I just completed mission 8 and now i'm able to see all the missions in my idroid. I unlocked the combat unit, and got an emergency call to go to mission 22, I died quickly. After that, it said something about Emmerich (Who is a major story character I think) and let me unlock the parasite suit. After the parasite suit briefing, I got a cutscene with Eli and an african boy. I looked it up, so now I know the true identity of Eli. Do I have to restart the whole game now?

Comment: Playing on the 360, bought legitimately and I have Xbox Live

Comment: Aside from an unusual cut-scene which inspired you to look up spoiler information, I don't see what's so bad about this bug.  Surely you can just keep playing and *not use the parasite suit* if you don't want to?

Comment: A bunch of other functions i'm not ready to manage quite yet have been unlocked too. I didn't know who huey emerich is but he made the walker gear I think so im not gonna look him up

Answer (score -1):

You didn't have a game breaking bug, you broke the intended sequence of events. You went directly from mission 8 to mission 22 and now you are surprised that you didn't catch everything in between.

That emergency mission, btw, is not as important as it seems. It introduces you to the Forward Operating Base and Invasions, the multiplayer component. If you don't respond to it right away, all that happens is that you lose some Mother Base personnel, and you can pick it up later after doing mission 21.

Comment: That mission is not supposed to appear until mission 21; it's definitely a bug.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Yeah, but not a *game breaking* one.

Comment: I've invested 20 hours into this game, and now I can't continue without major continuity/sequence errors so I have to restart. Pretty game breaking to me

Comment: Saying that a bug that skips ~ half of a game "not game breaking" is absolutely ridiculous. If you've missed half of the game, it definitely broke the game for you.